# Which way is efficient for calling stored procedure with async await in Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, async-await, entity-framework-6, asp.net-web-api2

I am using Entity Framework 6, VS15, DOT NET 4.5.

After reading couple of articles and posting questions here, I got some answers for making database operations asynchronous way, now, please suggest me which way is efficient in all mention below.

I added tables and stored procedure in Entity Framework and performing inserts with that. I really wants to make call asynchronous.

```
using (var DB = new JodoDataEntities())
{
    UserInfo UserInformation = await DB.UserInfoes.Where(x => x.Id == userInfo.UserId).FirstOrDefaultAsync();

    if (UserInformation != null)
    {
        UserInformation.Accuracy = userInfo.Accuracy;
        UserInformation.IsOnline = userInfo.IsOnline;
        await DB.SaveChangesAsync();
        return Ok();
    }
}
```

This is working fine, but I fill that, it is making DB calls two times, first fetching and then supply values in properties and then `SaveChanges()`, If everything happen in single call then it would be great.

Here `UpdateLocation` is my stored procedure:

```
using (var DB = new JodoDataEntities())
{
    DB.UpdateLocation(userInfo.UserId, userInfo.Accuracy, userInfo.IsOnline);
}
```

Above code is working fine and with single request too. but without asynchronous. And I need asynchronous call.

Here `UpdateLocation` is my stored procedure:

```
using (var DB = new JodoDataEntities())
{
    await DB.Database.SqlQuery<Task>("EXEC UpdateLocation {0}, {1}, {2}", userInfo.UserId, userInfo.Accuracy, userInfo.IsOnline).ToArrayAsync();
}
```

Above code is working fine too and asynchronous too. But is it correct way to call a stored procedure ?

Is there any other way to call stored procedures asynchronously with EF ?

Comment: Are you expecting your stored procedure to return something of a type called `Task`?

Comment: Yes, My store procedures are returning data too, and for that I am using List<getSearchList_Result2> Result = await DB.Database.SqlQuery<getSearchList_Result2>("EXEC getSearchList {0}, {1}", UserId, Search).ToListAsync();
                    return Ok(Result);

Comment: That's not what you have on the code in the question.

Comment: My mistake, But this is the way how I am binding result of SP in class object in business logic... Is it correct ?